# npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for spdx-exceptions@^2.1.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am getting this error while installing `create-react-app`. Manually installing `webpack-dev-server` also throwing the same error.

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for spdx-exceptions@^2.1.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any kind of proxy repository in your environment?

Comment: I am behind a corporate proxy. but i have don the npm config proxy settings properly.

Comment: More specifically, are you behind a proxy _repository_ (as opposed to, say, an HTTP proxy) like Nexus? If so, is this artifact available there?